# Rails relations in the same module throw uninitialized constant errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've got a couple of classes that look like this:

```
module Billing
  class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pricing_plan
  end
end

module Billing
  class PricingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
  end
end
```

This seems like it should work, but it's clearly not:

```
2.1.2 :001 > Billing::Subscription.first.pricing_plan
  Billing::Subscription Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `billing_subscriptions`.* FROM `billing_subscriptions`   ORDER BY `billing_subscriptions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant Billing::Subscription::PricingPlan
```

I've tried adding an explicit :class_name to the relations:

```
has_many :subscriptions, :class_name => 'Billing::Subscription'

belongs_to :pricing_plan, :class_name => 'Billing::PricingPlan'
```

but that gets me nowhere:

```
2.1.2 :003 > Billing::Subscription.first.pricing_plan
  Billing::Subscription Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `billing_subscriptions`.* FROM `billing_subscriptions`   ORDER BY `billing_subscriptions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant Billing::Subscription::Billing::PricingPlan
```

What's going on here and how to extricate myself from this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample code in http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-3-organizing-with-modules/, can you try:

```
has_many :subscriptions, :class_name => '::Billing::Subscription'

belongs_to :pricing_plan, :class_name => '::Billing::PricingPlan'
```

Note the leading `::` before `Billing`.